# Are there any http proxy for development which trigger tasks such as preprocess js before app response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

A scenario of mine:
I'd like to convert jsx file (React) into normal js.
And I need browserify or a kind because one of modules needs `require`.

Watching files for every modifications and repeating tasks make me feel overkill. Those tasks are only needed to be executed on timing of browser reload (on a request).
I know Rails development env does this, but in this case a node.js app.

So I do like to use a http proxy in front of my app and let execute those tasks before my app responses to browser.
Any tools available already? or any advice for implementing such a proxy?
I don't mind if those tools are available already in any language, (node.js, python or ruby), but if non I'd like to implement one with node.js.

Answer (score 0):

While app server is running on port 3000, I wrote a quick and dirty reverse proxy like this.
This proxy listens on port 31000 and just forward every requests, but if path is "/bundle.js" execute a command before forward the request.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({target: "http://localhost:3000"})
var proxyServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/bundle.js') {
    exec("jsx src/ build/ && browserify build/app.js -o bundle.js", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('error: ' + err);
      }
      proxy.web(req, res);
    });
  } else {
    proxy.web(req, res);
  }
});
proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});
proxyServer.listen(3100);
```